# What does the `-jvm-debug 5005` change in the JVM exactly?

Tags: java, scala, jvm

I know this opens your application or IDE to interact with the JVM by placing breakpoints in the source code but does anything change within the JVM. I.e. does the jvm run slower (when there are no breakpoints even), does the jvm run in a different way and basically I'm wondering what this flag does to the JVM internally.

Answer (score 2):

This options turns on [JDWP agent library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html). This library, being a [JVM TI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html) agent, enables many (if not all) JVM TI [capabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#capability). Some capabilities are harmless, but some do have performance impact.

For example, `can_access_local_variables` capability disables Escape Analysis making certain optimizations (like allocation elimination) impossible. `can_pop_frame` and `can_force_early_return` capabilities add some extra checks when interpreter calls into VM. `can_generate_method_entry_events` adds an extra check in the interpreter on each method entry and so on.

So, yes, the agent adds some overhead (though not too big), even when debugger is not active.